# Unable to access data inside a string (i.e. [ object Object ]) that was originally sent as a JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, express, axios

I'm using axios to send a JSON object as a parameter to my api. Before it post request is fired, my data starts of as a JSON object. On the server side, when I `console.log(req.params)` the data is returned as such

```
[object Object]
```

When I used `typeof`, it returned a string. So then I went to use `JSON.parse()`. However, when I used that, it returned an error as such

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

I looked for solutions, but nothing I tried seemed to work. Now I'm thinking I'm sending the data to the server incorrectly.

Here's my post request using axios:

```
createMedia: async function(mediaData) {
    console.log("SAVING MEDIA OBJECT");
        console.log(typeof mediaData)
        let json = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/media/new/${mediaData}`) 
    return json;
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can solve this?

Comment: Please add the `axios` piece of the code, since it's likely the source of your troubles

Comment: @charmeleon just updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code using `axios` to provide the `mediaData` in the body of the request instead of the URL:

```
createMedia: async function(mediaData) {

   console.log("SAVING MEDIA OBJECT");

    console.log(typeof mediaData)
    let json = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/media/new/`, mediaData) 

    return json;
}
```

In the backend (assuming you're using `express` here), you need to configure your application to use `bodyParser`:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

And then in your controller update your `console.log(req.params)` to `console.log(req.body)`; then restart your node server